# Argument Errors Possibly Concerning Type Mismatch?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, queue, double

I'm trying to take a text file with a list of numbers in it, enqueue them with a queue, store them as doubles, then dequeue them to another text file. I believe the issue lies within the difference in data types from when the file is read as strings to when it is stored in the queue as doubles, but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

I've tried reading the text file first them converting them from strings to doubles, storing them, as another queue, then dequeing the second queue with the doubles into the output file.

```
void queue::enqueue(double nums)
{
    if (isempty())
    {
        front = new numstack(nums);
        rear = front;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = new numstack(nums);
        rear = rear->next;
    }
}

void queue::dequeue(double &nums)
{
    numstack *temp = nullptr;
    nums = front->val;
    temp = front;
    front = front->next;
    delete temp;

int main()
{
    queue q;
    double nums;
    int numnums = 0;

    ifstream(input);
    ofstream(output);

    input.open("input.txt");
    while (input.get(nums))
    {
        q.enqueue(nums);
        numnums++;
    }
```

The error is happening in the main function happening in the line
input.open("input.txt);

The two errors are "no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::get [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" matches the argument list" and

"std::basic_istream> &std::basic_istream>::get(std::basic_streambuf> &,_Elem)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to '_Elem &"

Answer (score 0):

You can't extract `double` with [get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get):

> Extracts character or characters from stream.

You can use [std::atof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) to convert your char* input  to float though.

Comment: I understand this, but I'm not sure about its implementation. If I want to store them as doubles, when and how do I use the atof function to convert to doubles?

Comment: @wmade store in a char* and in the constructor call convert. You are passing by value to the ctor so conversation on call should be fine.